# Android - Change Action Bar Text Color

Tags: android, google-maps, android-actionbar

In my app I've got a theme without an action bar, but for one of my activities I need an action bar with white title. So, here is it's code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:title="Title"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<fragment android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

As you see, this activity also contains Google Maps Fragment.

Result:
[image: Result]

As you see, title color is not white. Why? I wonder.

Comment: You can use this in `styles.xml `for toolbar `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>` and apply the theme for toolbar

Comment: @Raghunandan Thank you! Now everything is OK :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After @Raghunandan: Just add this string to you `AppBaseTheme` in `styles.xml`:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this works only for API 21

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11){
            android.app.ActionBar ab=getActionBar();
            ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff3b3f54));//3b3f54 is html color code for purple, you can put any desired color code like ffffff for white
            ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```